# Delete item selected in cookies angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have a Json file in cookies like this :

```
 vm.data = [{
      "id": "4",
      "masp": "CPUXE5",
      "tensp": "CPU XEON E5 2600 V5"
    }, {
      "id": "5",
      "masp": "CPURZ5",
      "tensp": "CPU RYZEN 5 PRO"
    }];
```

I want when click button . This item will delete in cookies . How can i do that .
Here is my plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/ywFL8zfrXB5ClEAD2IR6?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`splice`** by passing the object

```
 vm.delete = function(item) {
        vm.cookies = JSON.parse($cookies.getObject('cart'));
        var index = vm.cookies.indexOf(item);
        vm.cookies.splice(index, 1);
        $cookies.putObject('cart', JSON.stringify(vm.cookies));
 }
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/AssmkWwtZZ9Q2mOxnlpA?p=info)**

Comment: Thank for help . But in your demo , when I click delete , it not delete ,I console.log and cookies not delete . It only delete when I click add , I want it delete and update in view when click delete . How can i do that

Comment: @NguyễnBảoDũng check the updated demo, https://plnkr.co/edit/AssmkWwtZZ9Q2mOxnlpA?p=preview